# Как мне ответить команде из командной строки

Tags: c++, winapi, cmd, openssl

Мне надо из кода в с++ ввести команду в cmd, но эта команда требует ввести ключ. Как мне с кода это сделать.

```
system("openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pbkdf2 -in C://ZeD_Crypto//test.txt -out C://ZeD_Crypto//testenc.txt");
```

Я ввожу такую команду в консоль, ее цель это зашифровать файл, для этого ей необходим ключ, который
надо ввести в консоли, причем два раза.
Моя программа проходится по флешке и шифрует все файлы и писать вручную каждый пароль это бред. Значит мне надо создать единый пароль для всех файлов флешки и в вводить его в консоль. Как это сделать я не знаю.

Comment: Поместите пароль в файл и используйте ключ `-pass file:passfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите пользоваться `system`, то запишите ввод в файл и передайте в командной строке через `<`.

Напомню, что в командной строке команды с `<` и `>` приводят к подстановке файлов соответственно вместо стандартного ввода и вывода.

```
prog <input > output
```

`prog` читает данные из `input` как если бы они вводились с клавиатуры, данные выводятся не на экран, а в файл `output`.

Comment: Не совсем понял, как это правильней реализовать

Comment: system я использую только потому, что немного не понял как пользоваться чем-то другим, если для моего случая есть что-то, что подходит лучше, то прошу пожалуйста рассказать

Comment: Есть варианты с `popen`, например, или с системным API. Реализовать — еще раз и медленно: записать то, что вы хотите вводить, в файл, и в конце строки в `system` добавить `< filename`.

Comment: Но это не работает так как должно.

Comment: Это не будет работать. Пароли вводятся не через входной поток. Это была бы ужасная дыра в безопасности. Когда надо ввести пароль программа обращается к консоли напрямую. А консоли у вас нет. Передайте пароль через файл: `-pass file:passfile`.

Comment: Правда можно и через входной поток если вы готовы немного рискнуть: `-pass stdin`.